# How to import a Google "Teachable Machine" to an Anaconda Jupyter Notebook in python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tensor, h5py

My problem is the import of a Google "Teachable machine" (https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) to a Jupyter Notebook in Python.
For testing I made an easy teachable machine and exported it to this tensor code:

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('keras_model.h5')

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('Path to your image')

# Make sure to resize all images to 224, 224 otherwise they won't fit in the array
image = image.resize((224, 224))
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference
prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

Is there a possibility to run this code directly in a jupyter notebook with the same functionality?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yea it will but make sure about the dependencies are having the same version or not. as I got problems because I was having a lower version of TensorFlow and Keras.
this is the preferred version to run Google Teachable machine.

```
Keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==2.1.0
pillow==7.0.0
```